# Error on installing Node.js windows 10 64bits

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, nvm

I had Node.js 5x installed and I download and Start the Node.js 8x installation and Wizard didn't install and rollback all operation and now I dont have any NodeJs and npm installed.

- My windows is 10 64 bits
- Node version is 8.11.3-x64

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I made the path and the error persist

[image]

I create the folder and Gave Full controll to everyone.
[image]

[image]

I dont have the right click run as Adm option here 
[image]

Im opening and install with/as CMD Adm mode 
[image]

[image]

choco doesn't runing after installation
[image]

NVM
[image]

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgjgD.png) nvm (ok, very interesting), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8h4v.png) After i installed node 8.11.0 (ok), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trueA.png) but the folder node_modules was empty (ok?), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuEBn.png) so I Installed node 6 with nvm (ok). [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raEVk.png)After i set to use node 8.11.0 in nvm (ok). [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTLj5.png) I tried to run the "npm install -g @angular/cli" and I get errors. [7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTsB8.png) I found the angular_cli in installation of node 6 (step [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuEBn.png)) and I tried to navigate to folder and run "npm install -g @angular/cli" again and I get others errors. Could you now whats Im doing wrong ? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: while installing did you install nodejs as adminstarator .???

Comment: I opened the cmd as administrator and a take the same issue.

Comment: Installation went bad (because error and there should be some files in "C:\Program Files\nodejs\" after installation or it'll definitely not work!) As @shahabvshahabi says, run the INSTALLATION as admin. (sorry for caps, just trying to be as clear as possible.) Right-click file and run as admin. If it still does not work, you can try installing with [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) or [chocholatey](https://chocolatey.org). The first is a node-manager which lets you install multiple versions of node at the same time. The second is a package manager for windows.

Comment: [1] nvm (ok, very interesting), [2] After i installed node 8.11.0 (ok), [3] but the folder node_modules was empty (ok?), [4] so I Installed node 6 with nvm (ok). [5]After i set to use node 8.11.0 in nvm (ok). [6] I tried to run the "npm install -g @angular/cli"  and I get errors. [7] I found the angular_cli in installation of node  6 (step [4]) and I tried to navigate to folder and run "npm install -g @angular/cli" again and I get others errors. Could you now whats Im doing wrong ? I'll put the pictures above.

Comment: The nvm-windows is great. Firstly I installed the Node.js 8 was I said and I gave the errors in npm angular cli . I solve the problem when I made a nvm unisntall and nnvm install the same veersion ( the final problem was the first installation dont create npm folder. When I reinstall (inside nvm-windows again) its create node_modele folder and npm files. Is working now. thanks so much @ippi and everyone!

Comment: You can log an error, perhaps this will help  
`node-v8.11.3-x64.msi /lxv C:\Temp\Nodejs.log`

Answer (score 0):

You could just set path from command prompt and it will work. Use this to set path:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Nodejs
```

Comment: This approach didnt work for me. I also create the folder and give permissions before install I was the same error.

Comment: Just uninstall node completely and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with Node 8.11.3. Resolved for me only by installing Node from Windows Binary (.zip)

Answer (score -1):

Just add:

```
;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

To the end of your Path variable on the "User variable" section of the Environment Variables on the System Properties.

After that, reopen your command prompt and type

npm
This should work.

Here is an image for reference

[image]

Comment: Same error, I made exacly this and I gave the same error!